# Entity Framework Storing Modification Info Design Suggestion?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In my application for some of my entities, i want to keep modification info ( username and modification time) on entity. To achieve it , i created an interface;

```
/// <summary>
/// Marks a trackable entity
/// </summary>
public interface ITrackableEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date the entity was modified
    /// </summary>
    DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user who modified the entity
    /// </summary>
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and created a base class that implements that interface ;

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseTrackableEntity : BaseEntity, ITrackableEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date the entity was modified
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user who modified the entity
    /// </summary>
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I created my own custom **DbContext** class which is inherited from **DbContext** and I overrode SaveChanges function as following;

```
...
foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    ...
    ...
    else if(entry.State == EntityState.Modified && entry.Entity is ITrackableEntity)
    {
        (entry.Entity as ITrackableEntity).ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        (entry.Entity as ITrackableEntity).ModifiedBy = this._webHelper.GetLoggedInUserName();
    }
}
    ...
return base.SaveChanges();
```

This is actually working but since I am new to entity framework I am not sure this is the best way to do it. At this point  my question is ; 
Is this design going to cause me problems in the future? Are there any better solution(s)?

Comment: This question would fit better at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is pretty good, but one potential issue is that you are tying your web layer to your database layer by using the `_webHelper.GetLogginInUserName()`.  As a general rule, you want to keep each of the layers separate.  What happens when you want to save data using something other than the web?  For instance a windows service or even a webAPI.

Our solution was to create an abstract base class:

```
/// <summary>
/// this holds all the standard auditing information.  Any EF table 
/// with a UI should extend this class
/// </summary>
public abstract class AuditableTable
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(789)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(789)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The downside of this is that you need to manually populate the audit info, but the upside is that we're not tied to the website directly and we didn't need to override any of the built in saving methods on the DataContext.

Comment: Thanks for heads up and you sample.I also didn't know about DateTimeOffset structure.

Comment: You have two options for storing dates: convert everything to UTC, or store the timezone with the date. We choose the latter.